# In ASP.NET MVC, what is the best way for model to let controller know what view to navigate to?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on my personal project where the model will be the speech recognition that exist throughout the duration of using the site, so basically it is a **while loop** that listen to requests of names and immediately navigate to the cshtml that match it, for example say I want to go to `Privacy.cshtml`, I just need to say it and the model will let the controller know to return that specific view

The problem is, I've had the model logic written out and everything is done already, it's just that I'm still stuck on the idea of navigating while the model loop still remain listening and so that model only need to start up once when the site request first executed  *(or is choosing ASP.NET MVC the wrong idea since the straight foward path, starting the controller method from model is quite abnormal?)*

I'm thinking of breaking the listening loop of model after receiving request and then just navigate to another view and start it again, and reference call controller from model is also a suggestion that I saw but it seem that this way is not recommended on every Stackoverflow post that I've read

Note: I could provide the code as well if it's needed, please just let me know. However, I don't think it'd be necessary for this problem

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is a server side web framework. It has no concept of speech recognition. So it's very unclear on how you plan for this to actually work somewhere.

Comment: @mason, I've got it working already due to System.Speech.Recognition but I just need to figure out away for the model to change the view right now. All other part worked out just great and as intended as well, might have been missing something but it perform just as expected :\

Comment: Do you ever plan to deploy this app to a server, and have your user access it from a different machine?

Comment: I might try to once I'm done, but as of right now it's just for personal use, Sorry for the lack of knowledge since I just started with this whole thing lately but are you suggesting that it won't work on other machines? Thank you

Comment: Absolutely. You're messing with a server side web framework, ASP.NET. It is only able to communicate to client browsers via HTTP, and thus you're limited to performing actions inside the browser's sandbox that the browser allows you to do. The .NET logic (such as System.Speech.Recognition) only runs on the server. Not on the client. So your whole architecture idea is flawed. If you want to run speech recognition on a client machine, then you need to write a desktop app that runs on their machine, or otherwise deal with some very complicated web audio solutions.

Comment: Understood, thank you so much for letting me know. However, in case I still wanted to work on it since it serve many purpose that can be use on my personal machine, do you have a suggestion for my current problem (the navigate one)?

Comment: ASP.NET normally is capable of processing HTTP requests, generating responses. You can't have something on the server just sending new HTTP responses whenever it feels like it - a response can only be to a request. Hence the name. You could potentially implement web sockets (via SignalR) to push data from server to client whenever the server wants to though.